Adapteing FloatBarrier for margins. How to get rid of an unwanted paragraph break?
I want to construct a marginbarrier (similar to FloatBarrier which does not work for material in the margins). It will have an argument, indicating how much space to reserve in the margin for the margin material of the next paragraph.
Trying to find solution for overfilling margins, I use the answer from    @John Kormylo received to a question on breaking pages. I understand  the difficulty for an automatic solution to break pages when margins fill and try now to build a variant to \FloatBarrier where I can reserve an amount of space ahead of a paragraph containing margin material. It will issue a \clearpage when not enough space in the margin is available and do nothing otherwise (similar to \FloatBarrier except for an argument giving the amount of space to request).
The advantage of this approach is, that after edits unnecessary marginbarrier need not be removed, thus making changes in the text less painful.
My code is using the code from @John Kormylo which I adapted, as good as I understand it. The result seems to work, except that it produces in marginpage a paragraph break and I cannot see why and how to get rid of it.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\filltext}{MARGIN NOTE TEXT Lorem ipsum 
    sapientem ne neque dolor erat,eros solet invidunt 
     lobortis est Utinam, enim commune corrumpit 
     Aenean erat tellus. Metus sed amet dolore justo, gubergren sed.}

\newcommand{\maintext}{\lipsum[75]}
 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginfix}

\usepackage{placeins} % has no effect

%for lualatex (when expecting pdflatex) %  required
\let\pdfsavepos\savepos
\let\pdflastxpos\lastxpos
\let\pdflastypos\lastypos

\newlength{\margintotal}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\global\margintotal=0pt}

\newsavebox{\textbox}
\newcommand{\continuepar}{\unvbox\textbox}

\newsavebox{\marginbox}
\newcommand{\marginpage}[1]
    {\savebox{\marginbox}{\parbox[b]{\marginparwidth}{#1}}%
        \global\advance\margintotal by \dimexpr \ht\marginbox+\dp\marginbox\relax
        \continuepar\marginpar{\box\marginbox}%
    }

\newcommand{\marginbarrier}[1]%
    {%
%       \par MARGINBOX \the\ht\marginbox\relax  
%       \par TEXTHEIGHT \the\textheight
%       \par RESERVE {#1}  
%       \par PROVIDED \the\dimexpr \textheight - #1
%       \par MARGINTOTAL \the\margintotal\relax 
%       \par MARGINBOX \the\ht\marginbox\relax 
%       \par REQUEST \the\dimexpr \textheight- #1 - \margintotal - \ht\marginbox\relax \par
        \ifdim 0pt >\dimexpr \textheight- #1 - \margintotal - \ht\marginbox\relax 
%           \par  FULL 
            \newpage
        \fi
    }

\begin{document} 
    \maintext  note1\marginpage{1 \filltext} and the rest of the para!
    \marginbarrier{190pt} 
    \maintext  note2\marginpage{2 \filltext} and the rest of the para!
    \marginbarrier{190pt}
    \maintext the paragraph should be broken and 
        the last line with the margin note  
        on the next page. note3\marginpage{3 \filltext} and the rest of the para!
    \marginbarrier{190pt} 
    \maintext note4  \marginpage{4 \filltext}
    \marginbarrier{190pt}   
\end{document}


you can probably just use the needspace package which will force a page break if you are a specified distance from the bottom

@DavidCarlisle: Interesting hint, thank you. I tried it. Unfortunately needspace will not account for the marginpar material in the margin. For this I need to construct marginpage which keeps track of the accumulated margin notes - but must not insert a page break.

It seems that the unwanted paragraph break comes from \continepar. If I remove this from the marginpage, it seems to work as desired. What is continuepar do? I cannot find any explanation with google... Where is it documented

I havern't looked at the margin code at all, but a simplistic algorithm wold be for each marginpar typeset in a box and then use needspace to ensure that that note would fit top aligned with the current line forcing a page break if not

\continuepar won't be documented in any website: you just defined it in the document you posted.

I just realized, but was not quick enough to edit my comment. My bad... It is code I copied and did not understand completely. What does /unvbox and \textbpx (defined but not used in the code) do?

not a lot, it's almost the same as \par the \unvbox forces end of the current  paragraph, but as the box register is empty nothing is added to the page at that point. That is it does the primitive end-of pargraph action, even if  \par has been redefined with a custom definition.
